# What is an "unescaped" TSV? What are the advantages of using it?

Tags: csv, escaping

I have seen the `unescaped TSV` term at a lot of places but I am not sure what it is and why is it needed? We have a dataset where the content-type is unescaped-tsv but I am just putting what looks like regular tsv in there. Not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 2):

A **TSV** stands for "Tab Separated Values" as explained here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab-separated_values

If the fields in the file actually contain characters like tabs, newlines etc. they would normally be escaped by placing the field value inside quote characters. This way, the reading application would "know" the data belongs to the same field.

If this escaping is left out, and there are fields that have tabs in their value, the file will not display properly because either tabs or linebreaks cause data to be shifted.

It all depends on what you intend to do with the file. If you want it to display properly in for instance Excel, you should use the escaped TSV or maybe even better, the more commonly used **CSV** (Comma Separated Values)
Personally, i see only disadvantages to using unescaped data files.